# Get value of multiple check boxes along with their parent input field

Tags: javascript, html, json, laravel, logic

I want some suggestions or a work-around for a situation I have. I'm building an *Access Management System* where I have to define permissions of *Create, Read, Update* and *Delete* for each module. By defining permissions to each module, an admin will create a **role** which will be assigned to a user later. I have around 14 modules and each module have four permissions as I mentioned earlier. I'm getting each permission's input by a checkbox, so I have several check boxes with a parent field having an `id` of each module. Here's some code to better understand what I want to achieve and what is my approach to it.

**HTML:**

```
<!-- Iteration loop starts here for rendering each module along with it's checkboxes -->
<tr>
    <th scope="row">{{$mod->m_name}}</th>
    <input type="hidden" name="module_id" value="{{$mod->m_id}}">
    <td><input type="checkbox" name="p_read" value="1"></td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" name="p_create" value="1"></td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" name="p_update" value="1"></td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" name="p_delete" value="1"></td>
</tr>
<!-- Loop ends here -->
```

**View:**
[image: rendered view of the above html]

**JavaScript:**

```
var foo = $('#formAddRole').serializeArray();
var json = {"module" : []};

$.each(foo, (key, obj)=>{
    var arr = {
        "module_id" : 0,
        "permissions" : {
            "create" : 0,
            "read" : 0,
            "update" : 0,
            "delete" : 0,
        }
    };

    if(obj.name == "p_read"){
        arr.permissions.read = 1;
        json.module.push(arr);
    }
    // conditions for 'p_create', 'p_update', 'p_delete' goes here...

    if(obj.name == "module_id"){
        arr.module_id = obj.value;
        json.module.push(arr);
    }
});
```

**The JSON structure I want to send to server:**

```
{"modules" : [
    {
        "module_id" : 1,
        "permissions" : {
            "create" : 1, 
            "read" : 1,
            "update" : 1,
            "delete" : 0,
        }
    },
    {
        "module_id" : 2,
        "permissions" : {
            "create" : 0, 
            "read" : 1,
            "update" : 1,
            "delete" : 0,
        }
    },
    // so on...
 ]}
```

I'm stuck at this point. The logic I'm using is not entirely useful to me. What could be a better approach, How can I achieve this in best way possible? Any help or suggestions would be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using PHP, just rename your fields as in the code below. No JavaScript is needed...

```
<tr>
    <th scope="row">{{$mod->m_name}}</th>
    <input type="hidden" name="modules[0][module_id]" value="{{$mod->m_id}}">
    <td><input type="checkbox" name="modules[0][permissions][p_read]" value="1"></td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" name="modules[0][permissions][p_create]" value="1"></td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" name="modules[0][permissions][p_update]" value="1"></td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" name="modules[0][permissions][p_delete]" value="1"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <th scope="row">{{$mod->m_name}}</th>
    <input type="hidden" name="modules[1][module_id]" value="{{$mod->m_id}}">
    <td><input type="checkbox" name="modules[1][permissions][p_read]" value="1"></td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" name="modules[1][permissions][p_create]" value="1"></td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" name="modules[1][permissions][p_update]" value="1"></td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" name="modules[1][permissions][p_delete]" value="1"></td>
</tr>
```

This will result in $_GET array in PHP:

```
"modules" : [
    [
        "module_id" : 1,
        "permissions" : [
            "create" : 1, 
            "read" : 1,
            "update" : 1,
            "delete" : 0,
        ]
    ],
    [
        "module_id" : 2,
        "permissions" : [
            "create" : 0, 
            "read" : 1,
            "update" : 1,
            "delete" : 0,
        ]
    ]
 ]
```

Comment: I'm using laravel for the backend. But I need to use the js as I'm sending the data through ajax requests.

Comment: Then just send `$('#formAddRole').serialize();`. And in PHP read `$_GET['modules']`.

Comment: I don't understand your question. You are looking better approach for what? Sending... Parsing...? What do you need exactly?

Comment: Sorry for the badly formatted and not-clear question, I am asking what could be the best approach to get and set the data of all the fields in my shown `json` output.

Comment: And you're right, I can send all the fields directly to php and let php handle all the fuss. Why didn't I think of that. :)
Any ways, please edit your answer and include your suggestion their for the community so that I can accept it.

Comment: Also you can name your checkboxes as `name="modules[{{$mod->m_id}}][permissions][p_read]"` and remove hidden input.